# JQuery's post(): the callback function is not called

Tags: jquery

I have this line:

```
$.post('/update', $('form').serialize(), function(){alert("hello")});
```

The problem is the alert is not shown.

This is the response:

```
Request URL:http://aib.localhost/update
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

No errors in Chrome Inspector.

I'm using jQuery 1.6.4.

Comment: looks right, have you tried the longer-hand $.ajax with explicit success handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem or not, try adding a semicolon after the alert.

```
$.post('/update', $('form').serialize(), function(){alert("hello");});
```

Comment: @tirengarfio: The missing semicolon cannot be the actual cause of the problem here -- see [semicolon insertion](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9).  [Here's a JSFiddle where the original code works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/B9v2m/)